# jquery slideUp() and slideDown() issue

Tags: jquery

I am quite new to jquery and having b/m problem with slidedown and slideup event.

I have horizontal navigation bar with 5 buttons (given as list items e.g sports,brand etc) which themselves are wrapped in div with id shoppingNav.

I have a slidedown menu which has CSS `display:none` (div with id `submenu_bg`).

I want `submenu_bg` to slidedown when I mouseover `#shoppingNav` and stay visible till I mouseout from `#shoppingNav`. I want individual buttons to `fadeIn` different icons on hover but submenu_bg should remain visible till I mouseout from whole on navigation bar( `#shoppingNav`).

What currently happening is `submenu_bg` keep on sliding down and up when hover from one button to another.

You can check the effect I want to get on [nike.com](http://www.nike.com/in/en_gb/).
I am not able to figure out how to do this. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Jquery code :

```
$(function(){
$('#shoppingNav').on('mouseover',function(){
    $('#submenu_bg').slideDown(200);
    });

$('#shoppingNav').on('mouseout',function(){
    $('#submenu_bg').stop().slideUp(200);
    });
});

<div id="shoppingNav">
        <ul>
        <li id="sports"><a href="#"></a></li>   
            <li id="brand"><a href="#"></a></li>                        
            <li id="clothing"><a href="#"></a> </li>                        
            <li id="footwear"><a href="#"></a></li>                         
            <li id="hotdeals"><a href="#"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="submenu_bg"><img src="_images/submenu_bg1.png" alt="some background"/></div> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a timeout, and then clear that timeout when mousing over a new list element so as to not slide the submenu again:

```
$(function(){
    var timer;
    $('#shoppingNav').on({
        mouseenter: function(){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            if (!$('#submenu_bg').is(':visible'))
                $('#submenu_bg').slideDown(200);
        },
        mouseleave: function(){
            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                $('#submenu_bg').slideUp(200);
            }, 500);
        }
    });
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/VAvwG/7/)

Comment: Thanks, for your efforts. Above code has worked for me. But just wondering if problem was due to event bubbling to children (li items) as each button was firing mouseover event seperately. And could I have used event.stopPropagation() somewhere in my original code. Also I will appreciate if someone can suggest me a good article or book in this regard. Currently I am reading Javascript and jQuery - the missing manual.   Thanks and bregds....

Comment: No, it's not really related to bubbling. The problem is that the slideDown starts when the mouse enters any list element, and the slideUp when the mouse leaves a list element, and when you move from one list element to another, the slideUp/Down will fire. Using a small timeout when the mouse leaves gives us a little window to cancel the slideUp when the mouse leaves if the mouse enters another list element, and doing a check to see if the element is visible prevents the slideDown from firing again.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed information. Can you advise a good book for beginner to intermidiate level in javascript/jquery/php-mysql. I know this is not related to this forum but just in case if you can advise me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be something to do with the way you are wrapping the event handlers.

I played around with this and managed to get it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/G9Te3/).

```
$('#shoppingNav').on('mouseover',function(){
  $('#submenu_bg').slideDown(200);
});

$('#shoppingNav').on('mouseout',function(){
  $('#submenu_bg').stop().slideUp(200);
});
```

​